# Rails 5.2 respond_to not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

With the very minimal example, I demonstrate my issue or I'm not doing it correctly.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :jobs
```

**/views/jobs/index.js.erb**

```
alert("Hello from index.js.erb")
```

Controller:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    # format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Going to `/jobs.js` I should get an alert but instead I see the text inside the `.js.erb` file. Why? I expect to get an alert. Correct? This would solve my issue where the js file not rendering or executing such as an append etc.

Comment: You typically render an HTML page (that loads javascript) or return a JSON response (a javascript object, basically, not a javascript file). You are telling the server to return a javascript file, and your browser is displaying the text of that file.

Comment: I am very noob with Js but maybe you should add a `;` at the end of your alert. Also make sure that you get directed to index action and expecting js answer. Maybe using `remote: true` (your doing ajax then js) or  `format: js` in the link

Comment: by the way are you sure you can call a specific format by adding `.js` to your controller name in path ? `/jobs/index?format=js` may give what you expect (ok I realise this is what Sunil explains, my brain just needs extra steps ^^)

Comment: I don't believe any browsers support executing Javascript directly, like that. So this doesn't seem to be a problem with Rails, but a limitation in your browser.

Comment: Many thanks for all comments. I've decided to go with `remote: true` for now until I can get it to work the way it should.